# installing plr on windows

Tags: windows, plr

I have Postgresql 9.0 on Windows 7 (32bit)
I have downloaded plr-8.3.0.13-win32 - extracted, put the dll in its place, edited the env variables and ran the plr.sql command with success.

```
R_HOME - C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\bin\i386
Path - ...C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\bin\i386 (I have also tried it with C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\bin)
```

However when I try to run a query that should directly talk to R the query freezes (never stops executing and I am unable even to cancel it).

```
SELECT * FROM plr_environ(); returns with a recordset.
SELECT load_r_typenames(); - never finishes, I have to stop the postgres procedure from task manager.
```

I had the same experience now on two different Win7 machine, one with 32 the other 64 bit and with Postgres 9.1 as well. I am sure I do something wrong here but I can't find out what.

Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve this.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set R_HOME=C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\